# A recurrence relation in an elementary problem in probability?

Tags: probability, distributions

While considering solving the following standard question in probability in an alternative way, I get stuck with a recurrence relation. The problem is as follows:

> A bag contains $N$ ropes. We pick up two randomly chosen ends and tie them together until no untied ropes are left. The problem is to find the expected number of loops.

Now there is a [standard and neat solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209/expected-number-of-loops) to the above problem. I tried to solve it instead by first finding the probability $p_{k,l}$ of getting $l$ loops at the $k$th stage, where both $k$ and $l$ can take the values $0,1,2,...N$. Further, it follows that at any time $l\le k$. Since with $N$ loops the probability of addition of a loop at the first step is ${N}/{\binom{2N}{2}}$, and at the the kth stage we have effectively $N-k$ ropes (possibly some consisting of more than one of the original ropes tied), we have the following recurrence relation:

$$p_{k,l}=p_{k-1,l} \cdot \text{Prob(No loop is added at $k$th stage)} +p_{k-1,l-1}\cdot\text{Prob(a loop is added at $k$th stage)}.$$

The above gives us
$$p_{k,l}=p_{k-1,l} \frac{2N-2k-2}{2N-2k-1} + p_{k-1,l-1} \frac{1}{2N-2k-1}$$

Now, with the base conditions $p_{1,1}=\frac{1}{2N-1}$ and $p_{1,o}=\frac{2N-2}{2N-1}$, how can we find $p_{N,l}$ in terms of $N$ and $l$?Is it even possible to find an approximate formula for $p_{N,l}$ by simulating $p_{N,l}$?

Comment: First comment: this looks like a proof by induction problem. Second comment: this problem isn't elementary at all.